# fscanf isn't going to the next line without integers present

Tags: c

i have the following text file:

```
123456789 0 Paulo Silva

555666777 2 Marta Nunes Cabral
4   1   12  12  2017    17  12  2017
5   0   20  04  2018

123123123 3 Maria Pimentel
5   2   01  10  2017    10  10  2017
5   1   13  01  2018    15  01  2018
4   0   17  04  2018
```

I have all of the code done, but whenever it tries to go to the next line from this part

```
5   0   20  04  2018  //27  04  2018
```

it jumps off the reading loop, But if i put some values like the ones in the comment there it reads all of it fine.

This is the code where it reads the file:

```
clientes * criaClientes(pClientes cli, int *tam){
FILE *f;
int nif = 0;
int nAlug = 0;
char nome[25] = "";
int idGuit = 0;
int estado = 0;
int count = 0;
int diaI = 0, diaE = 0, mesI = 0, mesE = 0, anoI = 0, anoE = 0;

pClientes novo;
pAlugueres novoAl;

f = fopen("Clientes.txt", "rt");
if(f == NULL)
    printf("Erro ao ler o ficheiro de texto");

while(fscanf(f, " %d %d", &nif, &nAlug) == 2){

    printf("Contagem: %d\n", count + 1);

    novo = malloc(sizeof(clientes));
    novo->al = NULL;

    if(novo == NULL){
        printf("Erro ao alocar memoria!");
        return cli;
    }

    fscanf(f, "%[^\n]", nome);
    removeSpaces(nome);

    novo->NIF = nif;
    novo->nAlugueres = nAlug;
    strcpy(novo->nome, nome);
    novo->banido = 0;

    while(nAlug != 0){
        fscanf(f, " %d %d %d %d %d", &idGuit, &estado, &diaI, &mesI, &anoI);
        nAlug--;

        novoAl = malloc(sizeof(alugueres));

        if(novoAl == NULL){
            printf("Erro ao alocar memoria!");
            return cli;
        }

        novoAl->ID = idGuit;
        novoAl->estado = estado;
        novoAl->dataInicio.dia = diaI;
        novoAl->dataInicio.mes = mesI;
        novoAl->dataInicio.ano = anoI;

        if(fscanf(f, " %d %d %d\n", &diaE, &mesE, &anoE) == 3){
            novoAl->dataEntrega.dia = diaE;
            novoAl->dataEntrega.mes = mesE;
            novoAl->dataEntrega.ano = anoE;
        }
        else{
            novoAl->dataEntrega.dia = 0; //Can this be the problem?
            novoAl->dataEntrega.mes = 0;
            novoAl->dataEntrega.ano = 0;
        }

        novoAl->prox = novo->al;
        novo->al = novoAl;
    }

    //Adicionar no inicio da lista ligada
    novo->prox = cli;
    cli = novo;

    count++;

}
    *tam = count;


    fclose(f);

    return cli;

}
```

Can the part where if it doesn't find a value, puts it to 0 be the problem?

EDIT: So after a lot of trial and error I got this resolution (just pasting part of the code not to cluster the question)

```
        while(nAlug != 0){
        fscanf(f, " %d %d %d %d %d", &idGuit, &estado, &diaI, &mesI, &anoI);

        nAlug--;

        novoAl = malloc(sizeof(alugueres));

        if(novoAl == NULL){
            printf("Erro ao alocar memoria!");
            return cli;
        }

        novoAl->ID = idGuit;
        novoAl->estado = estado;
        novoAl->dataInicio.dia = diaI;
        novoAl->dataInicio.mes = mesI;
        novoAl->dataInicio.ano = anoI;

        if(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), f) != NULL){

            int itens = sscanf(buffer, " %d %d %d", &diaE, &mesE, &anoE);
            printf("NUMERO DE ITENS: %d\n", itens);

            if(itens == 3){
                novoAl->dataEntrega.dia = diaE;
                novoAl->dataEntrega.mes = mesE;
                novoAl->dataEntrega.ano = anoE;
                itens = 0;
            }else{
                novoAl->dataEntrega.dia = 0;
                novoAl->dataEntrega.mes = 0;
                novoAl->dataEntrega.ano = 0;
            }
        }
        else{
            novoAl->dataEntrega.dia = 0;
            novoAl->dataEntrega.mes = 0;
            novoAl->dataEntrega.ano = 0;
        }

    novoAl->prox = novo->al;
    novo->al = novoAl;
}
```

Comment: When you have a variable amount of data on each line, if you use `fgets` to read each line from the file then `sscanf` won't be foxed in the same way that `fscanf` can be. But you ***must*** check the return value from the `scanf` function family. Although you have checked it sometimes - not always.

Comment: For example, having read the line with `fgets` into `buf` the processing of `items = sscanf(buf, "%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d", ...)` will tell you if 5 or 8 values were read.

Comment: @WeatherVane so i should use `fgets` with the `sscanf` to know how many items i need `fscanf` to read?

Comment: No, you don't use `fscanf` at all. You can't know how many items there are to read. Try to read as many as there can be and the return value from `sscanf` tells you how many you *did* read. So now you have read them, why do you want to read them again? Just ignore the ones that were not read. The advantage over `fscanf` is that `sscanf` can't overflow to the next line. It just stops.

Comment: @WeatherVane yeah i got it working after a lot of trial and error, gonna edit the question with the resolution

Comment: Make it an "update" please, rather than changing the question.

Comment: I just edited with the resolution i came up with

Comment: I notice you are using `fgets` after `fscanf`, which leaves a newline the buffer. Oh I see, you are reading 5 values with `fscanf` and 3 more with `fgets`. You could simplify the code and read (up to) 8 with `fgets` and `sscanf`.

Comment: I tried that but it would simply ignore the line if the last 3 values weren't there.

Comment: `fgets` does not ignore lines. Perhaps you were still using `fscanf`. Remove every `fscanf` and replace with something like `while(fgets(buf, ...) != NULL) { items = sscanf(buf, "...");  /*...*/ }`. It is very straightforward, you each have 5 results or you have 8.